# Assigning values to R matrix or data frame with adjacency vectors (specifically using row names and column names)

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, adjacency-matrix

I have seen other questions about getting the values of a matrix based on the vectors or tuples of indices but none about updating those values. I would like this:

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
rownames(mat) <- c("a","b","c")
colnames(mat) <- c("d","e","f")
rVec <- c("a","a","b")
cVec <- c("d","e","d")
nVec <- c(12, 13, 14)
mat <- func(mat, rVec, cVec, nVec)
```

To result in these being true:

```
mat["a", "d"] == 12
mat["a", "e"] == 13
mat["b", "d"] == 14
```

It seems to me that you should just be able to use `mat[rVec, cVec] <- nVec` as is the default functionality in something like numpy (python).

I don't have to use row names and column names but that is preferred to just using row and column numbered indices. I have explored sparseMatrix because that seems close to what I need but I didn't find anything. I have tried using mapply but it doesn't update the variable properly. I've tried using Vectorize but I find I need to use global variables which are breaking in the package I'm creating.

Comment: You can do `mat[cbind(rVec, cVec)] <- nVec`

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. This was a huge deal for me, thank you.